My french flag image has its colors swapped in gmail android dark mode
I'm using this image in a HTML template.

This is the french flag (blue, white, red) and I don't want these colors to be changed in dark mode. Gmail Android swaps colors to this, which makes no sense:

I have tried various things without success:

jpg image : colors are also changed
base64 image : not displayed
svg image : not displayed
... with 3 background colors: the blue and red colors are not swapped anymore but the white is still changed to black.


<table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-collapse: collapse;max-width:60px!important;">
  <tr>
    <td width="20" height="3" style="background-color: #0055A4;"></td>
    <td width="20" height="3" style="background-color: #FFFFFF;"></td>
    <td width="20" height="3" style="background-color: #EF4135;"></td>
  </tr>
</table>

The last try is the more promising but how can I avoid the white to be changed to black ?
Thank you !

I may have found the solution : simply add a 2px transparent margin above and below the image and colors are not changed in dark mode.
